# Generating BoundingBox for GeoJSON data

Tags: android, google-maps, geojson

I'm drawing GeoJSON polygons on my map using the Android Map Utils that Google provides (`compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'`). However, the GeoJSON I get does not include a bounding box, so sometimes the map is way off. Here's an example of the polygon stuff I get back:

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-88.138825,30.719378],[-88.138927,30.719386],[-88.139181,30.719409],[-88.139433,30.719429],[-88.139438,30.719429],[-88.139633,30.719446],[-88.139848,30.719461],[-88.140194,30.719487],[-88.140316,30.719495],[-88.140488,30.719505],[-88.140857,30.719522],[-88.141193,30.719544],[-88.141495,30.719559],[-88.141733,30.719571],[-88.142232,30.719596],[-88.142378,30.719602],[-88.142709,30.719616],[-88.143286,30.719639],[-88.143726,30.719657],[-88.14423,30.719677],[-88.144496,30.71969],[-88.144954,30.719712],[-88.146015,30.719757],[-88.146594,30.719782],[-88.146871,30.719794],[-88.147776,30.719835],[-88.148589,30.719868],[-88.148847,30.719876],[-88.149387,30.719903],[-88.150273,30.719944],[-88.151101,30.719981],[-88.151919,30.720016],[-88.152748,30.720054],[-88.153862,30.720098],[-88.154916,30.72014],[-88.156111,30.720194],[-88.157177,30.720241],[-88.157649,30.720266],[-88.158093,30.720292],[-88.158425,30.720314],[-88.158771,30.720349],[-88.15907,30.72038],[-88.159393,30.720415],[-88.160031,30.720494],[-88.160662,30.72057],[-88.161215,30.720637],[-88.161742,30.720696],[-88.162071,30.720736],[-88.16195,30.720897],[-88.161855,30.721036],[-88.161782,30.721148],[-88.161692,30.721293],[-88.161655,30.721359],[-88.161616,30.72142],[-88.161584,30.721479],[-88.161543,30.721555],[-88.161508,30.721632],[-88.161476,30.721714],[-88.161457,30.721782],[-88.161442,30.721843],[-88.161432,30.721883],[-88.161429,30.721898],[-88.161416,30.721954],[-88.161402,30.722014],[-88.161392,30.722065],[-88.161384,30.722116],[-88.161375,30.722182],[-88.16137,30.722242],[-88.161367,30.722323],[-88.161369,30.722429],[-88.161373,30.722566],[-88.161376,30.722761],[-88.161375,30.723117],[-88.161375,30.723257],[-88.16137,30.72343],[-88.161361,30.723634],[-88.16136,30.723863],[-88.161359,30.724048],[-88.161364,30.724241],[-88.161365,30.724525],[-88.16137,30.724805],[-88.161371,30.724934],[-88.161371,30.725025],[-88.161374,30.725131],[-88.161375,30.725532],[-88.161374,30.725576],[-88.161368,30.725633],[-88.161362,30.725683],[-88.16136,30.725726],[-88.161361,30.725776],[-88.161362,30.725839],[-88.161366,30.725911],[-88.161379,30.726238],[-88.161378,30.726573],[-88.161377,30.726897],[-88.161366,30.727084],[-88.161366,30.727149],[-88.161371,30.727222],[-88.161379,30.72733],[-88.161379,30.727437],[-88.161378,30.727548],[-88.161375,30.727627],[-88.161357,30.727818],[-88.161351,30.727923],[-88.161352,30.728014],[-88.161363,30.728186],[-88.16137,30.728395],[-88.161369,30.72872],[-88.161372,30.728957],[-88.161372,30.729211],[-88.161379,30.729351],[-88.161386,30.72945],[-88.161393,30.729556],[-88.161396,30.729655],[-88.161394,30.729824],[-88.161403,30.730129],[-88.161405,30.730268],[-88.161405,30.730457],[-88.161405,30.730763],[-88.161407,30.730923],[-88.161399,30.731075],[-88.161392,30.731214],[-88.161388,30.731399],[-88.161394,30.731602],[-88.1614,30.731923],[-88.161402,30.732116],[-88.161395,30.732547],[-88.161405,30.732797],[-88.161418,30.733154],[-88.161417,30.733291],[-88.161394,30.733911],[-88.161366,30.734341],[-88.161317,30.734959],[-88.161275,30.735447],[-88.161241,30.735907],[-88.161219,30.736167],[-88.161189,30.736516],[-88.161175,30.736742],[-88.161137,30.737199],[-88.161115,30.737806],[-88.161113,30.738298],[-88.161098,30.738838],[-88.161087,30.739417],[-88.161091,30.73989],[-88.161094,30.740051],[-88.161103,30.740272],[-88.161115,30.74039],[-88.161129,30.740519],[-88.161137,30.740623],[-88.161141,30.740794],[-88.161139,30.741026],[-88.16114,30.741196],[-88.161139,30.741207],[-88.160888,30.741207],[-88.160501,30.741239],[-88.160319,30.741246],[-88.160169,30.741256],[-88.160092,30.741259],[-88.160012,30.741266],[-88.15993,30.741275],[-88.159829,30.741294],[-88.159698,30.741321],[-88.159558,30.741336],[-88.159442,30.741339],[-88.159311,30.741336],[-88.159192,30.741321],[-88.159042,30.74129],[-88.15892,30.741243],[-88.158603,30.74109],[-88.157116,30.7401],[-88.156761,30.739874],[-88.156503,30.739646],[-88.156348,30.739506],[-88.156203,30.739375],[-88.155937,30.739118],[-88.155858,30.739047],[-88.155775,30.738987],[-88.155698,30.738943],[-88.155132,30.738695],[-88.154993,30.738633],[-88.154833,30.738573],[-88.154655,30.738522],[-88.153851,30.738351],[-88.153642,30.738305],[-88.153508,30.738289],[-88.153379,30.738265],[-88.153268,30.738247],[-88.153164,30.738224],[-88.153104,30.738193],[-88.153035,30.738138],[-88.152764,30.737898],[-88.152599,30.737736],[-88.152537,30.73767],[-88.152488,30.737632],[-88.152424,30.737614],[-88.152354,30.737621],[-88.152231,30.73763],[-88.151638,30.7377],[-88.151547,30.737709],[-88.151478,30.737711],[-88.151423,30.737709],[-88.151369,30.737685],[-88.150774,30.737301],[-88.150566,30.737133],[-88.150513,30.737064],[-88.150293,30.736767],[-88.150214,30.736663],[-88.150156,30.73658],[-88.150095,30.736495],[-88.150037,30.736417],[-88.15,30.736359],[-88.149954,30.736326],[-88.149898,30.736294],[-88.149803,30.736258],[-88.149727,30.736238],[-88.14966,30.736233],[-88.14956,30.736236],[-88.149547,30.73634],[-88.149498,30.736348],[-88.149468,30.736352],[-88.149436,30.73635],[-88.149407,30.736338],[-88.14937,30.736311],[-88.149318,30.736274],[-88.14929,30.736263],[-88.149257,30.736257],[-88.149196,30.736254],[-88.149123,30.736255],[-88.149061,30.736263],[-88.148859,30.736315],[-88.148731,30.736359],[-88.148678,30.736383],[-88.148622,30.736419],[-88.148565,30.736465],[-88.148503,30.736535],[-88.148415,30.736665],[-88.148374,30.736741],[-88.148346,30.73681],[-88.148313,30.736877],[-88.148247,30.736981],[-88.148121,30.737155],[-88.148033,30.737254],[-88.14795,30.737343],[-88.147721,30.737555],[-88.147602,30.737666],[-88.147521,30.737727],[-88.147463,30.737774],[-88.147416,30.737801],[-88.147367,30.737821],[-88.147322,30.737829],[-88.147279,30.737832],[-88.147238,30.737826],[-88.147191,30.737816],[-88.147026,30.737784],[-88.146803,30.73773],[-88.146348,30.737553],[-88.146272,30.737511],[-88.146226,30.737483],[-88.146193,30.737473],[-88.146167,30.737474],[-88.146125,30.73749],[-88.145879,30.737622],[-88.145622,30.737802],[-88.145505,30.73789],[-88.145414,30.737988],[-88.145306,30.738118],[-88.145167,30.738276],[-88.144963,30.738541],[-88.144876,30.738652],[-88.144831,30.738696],[-88.14479,30.738717],[-88.144736,30.738731],[-88.144685,30.738728],[-88.144623,30.738715],[-88.14458,30.738713],[-88.144556,30.738726],[-88.144535,30.738753],[-88.144512,30.738792],[-88.144464,30.738838],[-88.144244,30.739018],[-88.143998,30.739253],[-88.143962,30.739305],[-88.143922,30.739366],[-88.143807,30.739526],[-88.143768,30.739569],[-88.143726,30.739605],[-88.143664,30.73964],[-88.14321,30.739782],[-88.143043,30.73985],[-88.142966,30.739892],[-88.142928,30.739925],[-88.142899,30.739965],[-88.142874,30.740014],[-88.142602,30.740543],[-88.142572,30.740602],[-88.142543,30.740646],[-88.142503,30.740694],[-88.142447,30.740732],[-88.141954,30.741003],[-88.141234,30.741423],[-88.141177,30.741444],[-88.141108,30.741462],[-88.141054,30.741471],[-88.141001,30.741468],[-88.14095,30.741466],[-88.140911,30.741462],[-88.140877,30.741462],[-88.140855,30.74147],[-88.14084,30.741487],[-88.140826,30.741517],[-88.140822,30.741548],[-88.14082,30.741635],[-88.140821,30.74167],[-88.140819,30.741694],[-88.140809,30.741714],[-88.140794,30.74173],[-88.140756,30.741739],[-88.140718,30.741746],[-88.140685,30.741745],[-88.140645,30.741735],[-88.140587,30.74172],[-88.140534,30.741703],[-88.140486,30.741683],[-88.140448,30.741667],[-88.140417,30.741666],[-88.140399,30.741673],[-88.140387,30.741691],[-88.140377,30.741716],[-88.140355,30.741772],[-88.140273,30.741933],[-88.140254,30.741987],[-88.140244,30.742031],[-88.140244,30.742063],[-88.140243,30.742087],[-88.140232,30.7421],[-88.140207,30.74211],[-88.140166,30.74211],[-88.140108,30.742097],[-88.139973,30.742066],[-88.139942,30.74206],[-88.139915,30.742066],[-88.139886,30.742079],[-88.139836,30.742119],[-88.138954,30.742806],[-88.13627,30.742502],[-88.136308,30.74465],[-88.136214,30.745348],[-88.136201,30.745379],[-88.136179,30.745403],[-88.136148,30.745425],[-88.136096,30.745434],[-88.136049,30.745436],[-88.135818,30.745406],[-88.135776,30.745408],[-88.13573,30.745412],[-88.13567,30.745425],[-88.135535,30.745464],[-88.135498,30.745462],[-88.135474,30.745455],[-88.135451,30.74544],[-88.13543,30.745413],[-88.135409,30.745397],[-88.135386,30.745391],[-88.135358,30.745395],[-88.135343,30.745408],[-88.135296,30.745461],[-88.135252,30.745505],[-88.13521,30.74554],[-88.135172,30.745567],[-88.135127,30.745607],[-88.135075,30.745657],[-88.13505,30.745692],[-88.135024,30.745738],[-88.135006,30.745784],[-88.134999,30.745832],[-88.135006,30.745881],[-88.135033,30.745944],[-88.135064,30.746002],[-88.135082,30.746037],[-88.135088,30.746067],[-88.135087,30.7461],[-88.135075,30.746132],[-88.135054,30.746173],[-88.13503,30.746208],[-88.135009,30.74624],[-88.134995,30.746273],[-88.134986,30.746288],[-88.134975,30.746301],[-88.134962,30.746307],[-88.134948,30.746309],[-88.134932,30.746306],[-88.134912,30.746297],[-88.134883,30.746283],[-88.134854,30.746268],[-88.134813,30.746248],[-88.134764,30.746218],[-88.134665,30.746148],[-88.134589,30.746089],[-88.13453,30.746043],[-88.134507,30.746028],[-88.134482,30.746014],[-88.134452,30.746004],[-88.134427,30.745998],[-88.134394,30.745997],[-88.13436,30.745997],[-88.134328,30.746],[-88.134291,30.746007],[-88.134248,30.74602],[-88.134203,30.746035],[-88.134159,30.746056],[-88.134102,30.746087],[-88.134048,30.746129],[-88.134002,30.74618],[-88.13396,30.746239],[-88.133947,30.746269],[-88.133938,30.746293],[-88.133934,30.746327],[-88.133932,30.746364],[-88.133933,30.746407],[-88.133934,30.746453],[-88.133934,30.746503],[-88.133936,30.746522],[-88.133944,30.746541],[-88.133958,30.746559],[-88.133974,30.74658],[-88.133984,30.746599],[-88.133987,30.746617],[-88.133986,30.74663],[-88.133982,30.746644],[-88.133972,30.746655],[-88.133952,30.746665],[-88.133927,30.746673],[-88.133868,30.746683],[-88.133782,30.746697],[-88.133746,30.746706],[-88.133721,30.74672],[-88.133704,30.746736],[-88.133691,30.746755],[-88.133683,30.746786],[-88.133679,30.746821],[-88.133678,30.746862],[-88.133683,30.746887],[-88.133694,30.746909],[-88.133715,30.746928],[-88.133755,30.746946],[-88.133791,30.746962],[-88.133813,30.746978],[-88.133833,30.746997],[-88.133843,30.747014],[-88.13385,30.747031],[-88.133852,30.747048],[-88.133849,30.747062],[-88.133836,30.747073],[-88.133814,30.747079],[-88.133791,30.747081],[-88.133746,30.747084],[-88.133707,30.747091],[-88.133669,30.747101],[-88.133647,30.747106],[-88.133628,30.747114],[-88.133617,30.747124],[-88.133611,30.747141],[-88.133608,30.747156],[-88.133608,30.747178],[-88.133607,30.747197],[-88.133604,30.747217],[-88.133593,30.747233],[-88.133571,30.747252],[-88.133548,30.747262],[-88.133522,30.747272],[-88.133498,30.747282],[-88.13347,30.747299],[-88.133456,30.747313],[-88.133449,30.747328],[-88.133449,30.747346],[-88.133453,30.747362],[-88.133464,30.747374],[-88.133476,30.747386],[-88.133491,30.747401],[-88.133506,30.747417],[-88.133517,30.747432],[-88.133525,30.747447],[-88.133529,30.747462],[-88.133527,30.747477],[-88.13352,30.747489],[-88.133503,30.747498],[-88.13348,30.747506],[-88.13345,30.74751],[-88.133427,30.747509],[-88.133399,30.747503],[-88.133372,30.747496],[-88.133351,30.747494],[-88.133332,30.747499],[-88.133314,30.74751],[-88.133301,30.747526],[-88.133293,30.74754],[-88.133286,30.747556],[-88.133284,30.747574],[-88.133291,30.747588],[-88.133304,30.747603],[-88.133322,30.747616],[-88.133348,30.747629],[-88.133371,30.747642],[-88.133386,30.747657],[-88.1334,30.747673],[-88.133412,30.747691],[-88.133431,30.74772],[-88.133439,30.747737],[-88.133443,30.747755],[-88.13344,30.747771],[-88.133431,30.747783],[-88.133417,30.747797],[-88.1334,30.747805],[-88.13338,30.747809],[-88.133355,30.747808],[-88.133336,30.747808],[-88.133317,30.747812],[-88.133298,30.747818],[-88.133287,30.747826],[-88.133274,30.747841],[-88.133262,30.747858],[-88.133256,30.747877],[-88.133254,30.747895],[-88.133252,30.747924],[-88.133255,30.747949],[-88.133255,30.747974],[-88.133252,30.747997],[-88.133235,30.748034],[-88.133161,30.748169],[-88.133074,30.748355],[-88.133054,30.748379],[-88.13303,30.748402],[-88.133008,30.748431],[-88.132998,30.748448],[-88.132995,30.748465],[-88.132998,30.748482],[-88.133009,30.748495],[-88.133025,30.74851],[-88.133043,30.748522],[-88.133281,30.748692],[-88.133292,30.748704],[-88.133301,30.748718],[-88.133305,30.748732],[-88.133307,30.748753],[-88.133305,30.748775],[-88.133268,30.748966],[-88.133026,30.74896],[-88.132821,30.748958],[-88.132613,30.748957],[-88.132587,30.748957],[-88.132415,30.748956],[-88.132216,30.748957],[-88.131968,30.748957],[-88.131798,30.748957],[-88.13151,30.748954],[-88.131175,30.748955],[-88.130916,30.748954],[-88.130557,30.748947],[-88.130256,30.748935],[-88.129954,30.748931],[-88.129681,30.74893],[-88.129429,30.748925],[-88.129164,30.748924],[-88.128922,30.748923],[-88.12873,30.748925],[-88.128528,30.748931],[-88.128394,30.748941],[-88.128247,30.748951],[-88.128121,30.748968],[-88.127974,30.748994],[-88.127815,30.74903],[-88.127699,30.749062],[-88.127582,30.749098],[-88.127452,30.749143],[-88.127352,30.749184],[-88.127239,30.749233],[-88.127153,30.749273],[-88.127052,30.749329],[-88.126969,30.749378],[-88.126867,30.749446],[-88.126642,30.749584],[-88.126565,30.749631],[-88.126501,30.74967],[-88.126465,30.749635],[-88.126393,30.749565],[-88.12631,30.749473],[-88.126284,30.749443],[-88.126025,30.749132],[-88.125765,30.748829],[-88.1255,30.748507],[-88.125263,30.74823],[-88.125081,30.748001],[-88.124845,30.747717],[-88.124636,30.747471],[-88.124415,30.747191],[-88.124196,30.746919],[-88.124007,30.746693],[-88.123794,30.746433],[-88.123611,30.746229],[-88.123424,30.74604],[-88.123198,30.745811],[-88.122975,30.745596],[-88.122777,30.745397],[-88.122578,30.745196],[-88.122378,30.744998],[-88.122214,30.744832],[-88.1221,30.744722],[-88.12204,30.744673],[-88.122015,30.744642],[-88.122143,30.744548],[-88.122426,30.744346],[-88.122829,30.744058],[-88.123216,30.743779],[-88.123609,30.743497],[-88.1243,30.743009],[-88.124694,30.742722],[-88.125184,30.742375],[-88.125495,30.742154],[-88.125749,30.741984],[-88.125812,30.741944],[-88.125853,30.741923],[-88.125916,30.741888],[-88.12598,30.741854],[-88.126057,30.741816],[-88.126132,30.74178],[-88.126229,30.74174],[-88.126365,30.741689],[-88.126533,30.741637],[-88.126669,30.741601],[-88.126819,30.741569],[-88.127013,30.741531],[-88.127204,30.741496],[-88.127485,30.741447],[-88.127809,30.741395],[-88.128057,30.741354],[-88.128303,30.741314],[-88.128523,30.741277],[-88.12868,30.741249],[-88.128877,30.741213],[-88.129051,30.74118],[-88.129196,30.741152],[-88.129351,30.741118],[-88.129429,30.7411],[-88.129507,30.741079],[-88.12957,30.741062],[-88.129657,30.741035],[-88.129733,30.74101],[-88.12983,30.740976],[-88.129934,30.740935],[-88.130045,30.740887],[-88.130175,30.740828],[-88.130271,30.740779],[-88.130404,30.740706],[-88.130489,30.740654],[-88.130607,30.740576],[-88.130706,30.740504],[-88.130808,30.740425],[-88.130907,30.740346],[-88.131029,30.74025],[-88.131152,30.740148],[-88.131271,30.740052],[-88.131386,30.739958],[-88.131507,30.73986],[-88.131618,30.739773],[-88.131731,30.739683],[-88.131842,30.739591],[-88.131943,30.739506],[-88.132126,30.73936],[-88.132246,30.739261],[-88.132341,30.739182],[-88.132473,30.739076],[-88.132566,30.738999],[-88.132734,30.738863],[-88.13287,30.738753],[-88.133011,30.738637],[-88.133163,30.738513],[-88.133349,30.738364],[-88.133494,30.738243],[-88.133568,30.73818],[-88.13367,30.738096],[-88.1338,30.737986],[-88.133929,30.737873],[-88.134052,30.737761],[-88.134187,30.737638],[-88.134295,30.73754],[-88.134375,30.737464],[-88.134474,30.737368],[-88.13463,30.737219],[-88.134764,30.737089],[-88.134851,30.736994],[-88.135026,30.736815],[-88.135117,30.73672],[-88.135211,30.736618],[-88.135293,30.736531],[-88.135386,30.736425],[-88.135451,30.736348],[-88.135508,30.736276],[-88.135562,30.736201],[-88.135617,30.736119],[-88.135665,30.736037],[-88.135702,30.735961],[-88.13574,30.735878],[-88.135778,30.735772],[-88.135815,30.735652],[-88.135861,30.735483],[-88.135916,30.735259],[-88.135946,30.73514],[-88.136003,30.734895],[-88.13606,30.734662],[-88.136106,30.734482],[-88.136152,30.734293],[-88.136193,30.734115],[-88.136235,30.73391],[-88.136264,30.733754],[-88.136282,30.733621],[-88.136304,30.733441],[-88.136313,30.733312],[-88.136321,30.733103],[-88.136323,30.732956],[-88.136319,30.732683],[-88.136309,30.732458],[-88.136301,30.732264],[-88.13629,30.731981],[-88.136283,30.731762],[-88.136275,30.731519],[-88.136262,30.731154],[-88.136251,30.730828],[-88.136247,30.730594],[-88.13624,30.730347],[-88.136232,30.730142],[-88.13623,30.73002],[-88.136224,30.729878],[-88.13622,30.729688],[-88.136211,30.729404],[-88.136205,30.729143],[-88.136197,30.728916],[-88.13619,30.728696],[-88.136177,30.728474],[-88.136167,30.728194],[-88.136158,30.727943],[-88.136151,30.727669],[-88.136147,30.727423],[-88.136146,30.727202],[-88.136149,30.727029],[-88.136151,30.726858],[-88.136157,30.726651],[-88.136161,30.726376],[-88.136163,30.726128],[-88.136164,30.725844],[-88.136167,30.725572],[-88.136164,30.725318],[-88.136159,30.725085],[-88.13614,30.724638],[-88.136118,30.724255],[-88.136095,30.723822],[-88.136083,30.723563],[-88.136071,30.723161],[-88.136059,30.722664],[-88.136056,30.722224],[-88.136062,30.721896],[-88.136078,30.721565],[-88.136093,30.72123],[-88.136111,30.720908],[-88.13612,30.720527],[-88.136121,30.720172],[-88.136113,30.719843],[-88.136106,30.719487],[-88.136099,30.719248],[-88.136101,30.718929],[-88.136104,30.718792],[-88.136117,30.718637],[-88.136126,30.718554],[-88.13615,30.718471],[-88.136194,30.718375],[-88.136261,30.718437],[-88.136446,30.718573],[-88.136579,30.718667],[-88.13671,30.718751],[-88.136846,30.718833],[-88.136979,30.718902],[-88.137137,30.718979],[-88.137278,30.719042],[-88.137451,30.719109],[-88.137627,30.719169],[-88.137789,30.719215],[-88.13794,30.719255],[-88.138076,30.719286],[-88.138215,30.719312],[-88.138222,30.719313],[-88.138393,30.719336],[-88.138544,30.719353],[-88.138718,30.719371],[-88.138825,30.719378]]]}
```

And I'm just adding it to the map by doing:

```
            geoJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), geoJsonObject);
            layer.addLayerToMap();
```

However, because there are no "bounds" supplied in the KVP data, so any time I try to do, `layer.getBoundingBox()`, I always get a return value of `null`. Is there a way to generate the bounding box myself once I know the coordinates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the sources of [GeoJsonLayer.java](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonLayer.java) and [GeoJsonParser.java](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonParser.java) it's obvious that there's no code to calculate the bounding box. Even the [parseFeatureCollection()](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonParser.java#L413) method just parses the bounding box if it's in the GeoJSON data.

However the bounding box is a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds) object and the class has a nested [Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder) class which can be used to build a `LatLngBounds` object:

```
// Get the bounding box builder.
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();

// Get the coordinates
for (GeoJsonFeature feature : layer.getFeatures()) {
    if (feature.hasGeometry()) {
        GeoJsonGeometry geometry = feature.getGeometry();

        List<? extends List<LatLng>> lists =
                ((GeoJsonPolygon) geometry).getCoordinates();

        // Feed the coordinates to the builder.
        for (List<LatLng> list : lists) {
            for (LatLng latLng : list) {
                builder.include(latLng);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Assign the builder's return value to a bounding box.
LatLngBounds bb = builder.build();
```

So, if you have only `GeoJsonPolygons` to draw it's not that much hassle to get a bounding box.

For a more complete solution you would have to build a more elaborate mechanism to extract the coordinates from any [GeoJSON geometry object type](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometry-objects). They are all implementations of the [GeoJsonGeometry](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonGeometry.html) interface. The first thing is to differentiate between [GeoJsonGeometryCollection](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonGeometryCollection.html) and all the rest:

```
private LatLngBounds getLatLngBoundingBox(GeoJsonLayer layer) {

    List<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (GeoJsonFeature feature : layer.getFeatures()) {

        if (feature.hasGeometry()) {
            GeoJsonGeometry geometry = feature.getGeometry();

            if (geometry.getType().equals("GeometryCollection")) {
                List<GeoJsonGeometry> geometries =
                        ((GeoJsonGeometryCollection)geometry).getGeometries();

                for (GeoJsonGeometry geom : geometries) {
                    coordinates.addAll(getCoordinatesFromGeometry(geom));
                }
            }
            else {
                coordinates.addAll(getCoordinatesFromGeometry(geometry));
            }
        }
    }

    // Get the bounding box builder.
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();

    // Feed the coordinates to the builder.
    for (LatLng latLng : coordinates) {
        builder.include(latLng);
    }

    LatLngBounds boundingBoxFromBuilder = builder.build();

    //return boundingBox;
    return boundingBoxFromBuilder;
}
```

The actual code (may have bugs) for extracting the coordinates would be something like:

```
private List<LatLng> getCoordinatesFromGeometry(GeoJsonGeometry geometry) {

    List<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    // GeoJSON geometry types:
    // http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometry-objects

    switch (geometry.getType()) {
        case "Point":
            coordinates.add(((GeoJsonPoint) geometry).getCoordinates());
            break;
        case "MultiPoint":
            List<GeoJsonPoint> points = ((GeoJsonMultiPoint) geometry).getPoints();
            for (GeoJsonPoint point : points) {
                coordinates.add(point.getCoordinates());
            }
            break;
        case "LineString":
            coordinates.addAll(((GeoJsonLineString) geometry).getCoordinates());
            break;
        case "MultiLineString":
            List<GeoJsonLineString> lines =
                    ((GeoJsonMultiLineString) geometry).getLineStrings();
            for (GeoJsonLineString line : lines) {
                coordinates.addAll(line.getCoordinates());
            }
            break;
        case "Polygon":
            List<? extends List<LatLng>> lists =
                    ((GeoJsonPolygon) geometry).getCoordinates();
            for (List<LatLng> list : lists) {
                coordinates.addAll(list);
            }
            break;
        case "MultiPolygon":
            List<GeoJsonPolygon> polygons =
                    ((GeoJsonMultiPolygon) geometry).getPolygons();
            for (GeoJsonPolygon polygon : polygons) {
                for (List<LatLng> list : polygon.getCoordinates()) {
                    coordinates.addAll(list);
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    return coordinates;
}
```

You would then use the code like:

```
LatLngBounds bb = getLatLngBoundingBox(layer);
```

Comment: About an hour after posting this question, I came to this exact answer myself! Thank you for taking the time for the write-up, and this works 100% for anyone else running into the same question.