# Getting coordinates from GeoJson

Tags: android, geojson

I have geojson layer in my app. It's being loaded dynamically. Basically, I need to add marker to all geojson features so I need "position".

I have loop like this :

```
 for (GeoJsonFeature feature : layer.getFeatures()) {
                feature.setPolygonStyle(polygonStyle);   
            }
```

But I have no idea how to get coordinates from feature. I've tried this method :

```
private List<LatLng> getCoordinatesFromGeometry(Geometry geometry) {

        List<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

        // GeoJSON geometry types:
        // http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometry-objects

        switch (geometry.getGeometryType()) {
            case "Point":
                coordinates.add(((GeoJsonPoint) geometry).getCoordinates());
                break;
            case "MultiPoint":
                List<GeoJsonPoint> points = ((GeoJsonMultiPoint) geometry).getPoints();
                for (GeoJsonPoint point : points) {
                    coordinates.add(point.getCoordinates());
                }
                break;
            case "LineString":
                coordinates.addAll(((GeoJsonLineString) geometry).getCoordinates());
                break;
            case "MultiLineString":
                List<GeoJsonLineString> lines =
                        ((GeoJsonMultiLineString) geometry).getLineStrings();
                for (GeoJsonLineString line : lines) {
                    coordinates.addAll(line.getCoordinates());
                }
                break;
            case "Polygon":
                List<? extends List<LatLng>> lists =
                        ((GeoJsonPolygon) geometry).getCoordinates();
                for (List<LatLng> list : lists) {
                    coordinates.addAll(list);
                }
                break;
            case "MultiPolygon":
                List<GeoJsonPolygon> polygons =
                        ((GeoJsonMultiPolygon) geometry).getPolygons();
                for (GeoJsonPolygon polygon : polygons) {
                    for (List<LatLng> list : polygon.getCoordinates()) {
                        coordinates.addAll(list);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        return coordinates;
    }
```

However it doesn't seems to work. Any help, please ?

Comment: _"But I have no idea how to get coordinates from feature. "_ Referring to [http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonFeature.html](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonFeature.html) a `GeoJSONFeature` has the `getGeometry()` method which gives you a `GeoJsonGeometry` which is one of the geometry types like a point, line, multiline etc. and you already have the code for extracting the individual coordinate points from those. So, what is the problem?

Comment: I suppose you want just one marker for each feature. Then of course extracting all the coordinate points is a starting point but not enough. You need to decice how you want to decide the marker location for a feature. You could have a look at [calculating the bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486951/generating-boundingbox-for-geojson-data/37497144#37497144) for a feature and then calculating the middle point of the bounding box. I'm not sure this is the solution, but at least something to consider.

Comment: Of course if the GeoJSON features are quite small (in relation to expected map zoom levels) it might be enough to just pick one of the coordinate points e.g. the first one and then there's no point in anything more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I extracted first coordinate from geojson in JAVASCRIPT

```
function getFirstCorrdinatesFromData(result){

    var firstCordinate = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        //alert(result[i].geometry.type)
        if(result[i].geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon') {
            
            let coordinates = result[i].geometry.coordinates;
            firstCordinate.push(coordinates[0][0][0]);


  }else if(result[i].geometry.type == 'Polygon') {
    let coordinates = result[i].geometry.coordinates;
            firstCordinate.push(coordinates[0][0]);
     
  }else if(result[i].geometry.type == 'Point') {
    let coordinates = result[i].geometry.coordinates;
            firstCordinate.push(coordinates);
     
  } 
      }
      return firstCordinate;
}
var arrayOfCoordinates=getFirstCorrdinatesFromData(data.features);
```

This is how my json looks :https://pastebin.com/80QDtt93